# facebook - permission for alerting when user changed profile picture

Tags: facebook

What is the facebook permission that my app must request if I wish to know when the user using my app changed their profile picture. I need to know the time just in case they change it.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user changed their profile picture?

Comment: I have an app that allows users to measure their popularity based on their profile picture. I want to know when they change their picture so that I can tell them how effective the new picture was.

Comment: I'm guessing you have to poll and check when it changes. You can see if Webhooks will tell you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the pointer.